# SKShapenode how to create trace?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I'm trying to create trace effect to ball shape SKNode, I can try with EmitterNode, but it creates like particle effect, I need help creating an effect similar to the attached screen below, please help how I can create.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as a **trail effect**. Sometimes the result of motion blur, we're conditioned to know well through slow shutter speeds in 24fps movies.

Here's a github repo that creates something very similar:

https://github.com/dionlarson/Duet-Trail-Effect-SpriteKit-Playground